# Modal Window not working

Tags: qt, modal-dialog, qml, qtquick2

I have a main window in `QML` and I want that when I **click** on a `button`, a `modal window` can pop.

I tried this but `it is not working` and I don't understand why:

```
Rectangle {
    id: root

    ...

    Button {
        onClicked: {
            var factory = Qt.createComponent( "DialogWindow.qml" );
            var dialog = factory.createObject(root);
            dialog.show();
        }
   }
}
```

*main.qml*

```
Window { //I also tried "Dialog"
    height: 240
    width: 320
    title: qsTr( "Popup" )
    visible: true
    modality: 1

    ListView{
        //My stuff
    }
}
```

*DialogWindow.qml*

And here is the error :

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'show' of null
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: If you use a `Dialog` it should by [modal by default](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-dialog.html#modality-prop) - for me it works flawless if I don't mess with the modality at all. If I set `modality: 1` I get the error: `Invalid property assignment: unknown enumeration`. For `modality: Qt.WindowModal` it is fine again. Same goes for `Qt.ApplicationModal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the propery doc of [modal](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#modality-prop) it says

> Possible values are Qt.NonModal (the default), Qt.WindowModal, and
>   Qt.ApplicationModal.

So why don't you use them instead of 0 or 1 hardcoded?

```
modality: Qt.ApplicationModal
```

Comment: Hello, in fact it was a mistake from this thread example.
If I write `dialog.show()`, I will have the following error `TypeError: Cannot call method 'show' of null`

Comment: ok so your `factory.createObject(root)` fails and returns `null`? It should work like that.

Comment: Yes I think so. But I don't understand why. It is probably because of `modality`.

Comment: you can try and print out the error like this `console.error(factory.errorString());` after `factory.createObject`

Comment: So it say  `Invalid property assignment: unknown enumeration`.
If I read modality doc, it say that it is a `WindowModal` so an `enum` type (1 or 0 I assume)

Comment: I changed my answer, look at the change :)

Comment: This work great ! I thought I had to convert them as values. Thanks a lot for your help, have a good day :)